# Why do I get the following error? Valueerror: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, list, numpy

I would like to have as output a list where each element is a string. why do I get the following error?

```
hhh[i,j]=['Ok']
```

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

```
yyyy=np.asarray([[ 52.187,  39.141,  26.094],
   [ 57.164,  42.874,  28.583],
   [ 71.619,  53.716,  35.811],
   [ 21.565,  16.174,  10.783],
   [ 67.592,  50.694,  33.796],
   [109.85 ,  82.39 ,  54.928]])
hhh=np.zeros((6,3))
print(hhh)    


for i in range(0,6): 
    for j in range(0,3):
        if yyyy[i,j]<= 100:
            hhh[i,j]=['Ok']
        else:
            hhh[i,j]=['No']
```

My expected result is to obtain a list hhh[6,3] of 'Ok' or 'No'

Comment: you can't set another array as a value into an array which accepts only `float64` values

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're using `NumPy`, you have [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for this:

```
np.where(yyyy<=100, 'OK', 'NO')

array([['OK', 'OK', 'OK'],
       ['OK', 'OK', 'OK'],
       ['OK', 'OK', 'OK'],
       ['OK', 'OK', 'OK'],
       ['OK', 'OK', 'OK'],
       ['NO', 'OK', 'OK']], dtype='<U2')
```

---

If you want a list just add, `.tolist`, `np.where(yyyy<=100, 'OK', 'NO').tolist()`

---

Note that you're getting an error given that by default `np.zeros` will create a `ndarray` of `dtype('float64')`. Instead you could define a `np.empty` ndarray with the same shape as `yyyy` and with `dtype('<U2')`, i.e a length `2` unicode string:

```
hhh = np.empty(shape=yyyy.shape, dtype='U2')

for i in range(0,6): 
    for j in range(0,3):
        if yyyy[i,j]<= 100:
            hhh[i,j]='Ok'
        else:
            hhh[i,j]='No'
```

Comment: Thanks again it works correctly now. Great, 1000 points for yatu

Comment: @chrisis https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers (What should I do when someone answers my question?)